# Pixel 2: no Play store after lineageOS and gapps installation

Tags: google-play-store, lineageos

I installed Lineage 18 on a Pixel 2 without issues. I followed the official guide (https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/walleye/install).

The problem is that there is no Play store after the first boot. I wiped again twice and redid everything without issues. Still no Play store and firstboot is normal.

I tried to wipe, install lineage, firstboot, then boot to recovery to install the gapps.zip, but of course that expectedly created problems (system not booting, sending straight to recovery).

I tried gapps nano and pico, same thing.

I'm out of ideas, any help will be very welcomed. I flashed multiple devices in the past and never stumbled on this issue.

Could that be a a-b slot thing? I doubt adb sideloading lineage and then gapps right after one another would send one to A and the other to B. Maybe MindTheGapps would behave differently?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved!

Boot to TWRP, sideload Lineage, from TWRP reboot to Recovery. Lineage Recovery will load. Sideload the gapps. Reboot to system.

A few things:

- I did get stressed out about the slot thing, but from TWRP, rebooting to Recovery sends to Lineage Recovery (along with a different slot [sometimes?)], so things get a little counter intuitive.
- In the past I flashed a Nexus 6P, an S4, an S5 and a Nexus 5. It was never necessary to reboot to recovery between loading Lineage (or Cyanogen back then) and the gapps.
- The wiki doesn't mention that it is required to reboot to recovery to install the gapps after sideloading Lineage. I would update it to add this detail, along with the fact that you go from TWRP to Lineage Recovery in the process.